# How to increase font size only for desktop device

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, mobile, jquery-mobile

Working on ASP.Net MVC project, I don't want to just say... **looking for a way to detect mobile / desktop device.** as on [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) web site, they say *...your first step is to try to avoid it if possible. Start by trying to identify **why** you want to do it.*

I searched and found a lot of answer but none of them are efficient or an official way to detect mobile device that's why I start with explaining why I need it.

First task given to me was to increase **font size** for the entire web site and I did it and it is working well using below code

```
    $(function increaseFont() {
    document.body.style.zoom = "150%"
});
```

now I got new requirement to decrease size to normal for **mobile device only**... so I'm thinking of having a **if** conditional before the above JS function to detect if device is mobile or desktop.

Any idea please?

Comment: I prefer use media query like https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use standard media queries to change CSS properties. 
The code you're looking for would probably be something like the following:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { /* Anything larger than a tablet */
  body {
   font-size: large; /* Increases every font size */
  }
}
```

For more information, you could check out the [W3 Schools Website](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Tim VanH.  The rest is working fine but I'm now more concerned about the **iPad Pro (10.5 inch)** which has **834 * 1112** and **Kindle Device (800 * 1280)** view port as seen on my browser **Firefox Responsive Design Mode.**  Their view port is larger than **768** you mentioned.  _Not sure if there are considered Mobile devices or Not ?_

Comment: Either should be fine. They are counted as tablets, which makes them rather ambiguous corner-cases (in my experience). If you want to exclude them from increasing the font-size, just adjust `min-width` to 835.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim VanH

Answer (score 0):

You can read out the window inner width with JavaScript.

This is probably the if condition you are asking for:

```
if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
   // do stuff for desktop devices
}
```

The value in the if condition determines the minimum required width (in px) of the viewport, to execute the code in its body.

Comment: On [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser/11381730#11381730) they say do not reply upon **window.innerWidth for detecting mobile devices.** it's a hidden comment.